# My text content auto entities html tag after submit

Tags: php, wordpress, html-entities

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrLcp.png)

I have strange issue with my text content on text editor field. When I have not much content, it work correct. But when I input a lot of content on many fields, the content auto entities all html tags end of fields.
I do not know how to explain my issue. You can see image I attached. Anyone can help me detect this, thanks.

Comment: Are you seeing html tag in Text view?

Comment: Yes, I have see html tag on Text view

Comment: I don't think that's a problem. Text view shows the html version actually. You have to edit using Text view and use Visual to view the results only.

Comment: No, I misunderstood your point. On text view tab, it show htmlentities code https://prnt.sc/26tt8nd

Comment: I see what you meant now. Please check this: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/295510/wordpress-turns-html-code-to-html-entities